# set and get using synchronization tool error in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, data-synchronization

i have an error in this code that's the thread set 2 value instead of one when the program start , the program mustn't set the next value before get the current

this is the main class

```
class DATA 
{
    private int value=0;
    Lock lock;
    Condition co;
    Boolean IstReady=false;

   public DATA()
   {
       IstReady=false;
       lock = new ReentrantLock();
       co=lock.newCondition();
        }
   public void set(int x) throws InterruptedException
   {
       lock.lock();// try
       while(IstReady==true)
           co.await();
       value=x;

       IstReady=true;
       co.signal();
       lock.unlock();
   }
  public int get() 
  {

      int ret=0;
 try{
      lock.lock();
      while(IstReady==false)
      co.await();
      ret=value;

      co.signal();

     //lock.unlock();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
 finally{
     lock.unlock();
        IstReady=false;


  }
    return ret;
}
}
        }
    }
```

and this the set() and get() class

```
class setter extends Thread
{
    DATA D;
    public setter(DATA X)
    {
        D=X;
}

    @Override
    public void run()
{
    Random T=new Random();
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            int M=T.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println("setter set"+M);

            D.set(M);



        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(setter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }



    }
}


public class Newtest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    DATA x=new DATA();
    setter s=new setter(x);
    getter g=new getter(x);
    s.start();
    g.start();

    }

}
```

i think the error is in the set() and get() method in DATA class

Comment: The values you expect to read in a locked block should be written to, inside the locked block.

Comment: i do that in set and get method but not work correctly

Comment: How do you determine whether your code works? The print statements *outside the locked code section* will not tell you that, especially when using random data. Try it with simple ascending `int` values… By the way, the class `Condition` is named such as it represents a *condition*. So if you have *two conditions* like “have value” and “have no value” you should create two `Condition` instances and associate them with either condition and `await` and `signal` the appropriate condition. Once you have more than two threads that might matter. — Or just use either `Exchanger` or `SynchronousQueue`…

Comment: the tow Condition use the same lock ? / the problem  is when the set method  set a value  it dose not lock and set another value

Comment: when i use  thread.sleep(10)  , the code work correctly